# Push elements to the sides Antd (align one to the left and one to the right)

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using [Antd with React](https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce). I want to add a space between a two elements such that one element aligns on the left and the other element to the right of the maximum available space. See the attached image with a Text and Switch.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be achieved using a Grid where you add a greedy Col inbetween:

```js
<Form.Item>
    <Row>
        <Col><Typography>Essential</Typography></Col>
        <Col flex="auto"></Col>
        <Col ><Switch defaultChecked /></Col>
    </Row>
</Form.Item>
```